# carousel inside a carousel item is not working in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my code. There is a parent slider. Inside that slider's class every "item" there is another slider. The outer slider is working well but the nested sliders are disappearing whenever sliding back.

If you run this code using bootstrap you'll surely notice that.

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-sx-12">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        1
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        2
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </div><!--end of item-->
        </div><!--end of col-->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-sx-12">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        4
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic3" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic3" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </div><!--end of item-->
        </div><!--end of col-->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

JAVASCRIPT :

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').carousel();
$('#carousel-example-generic2').carousel();
$('#carousel-example-generic3').carousel();
```

HTML :

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-sx-12">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item2 active">
                        1
                    </div>
                    <div class="item2">
                        2
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </div><!--end of item-->
        </div><!--end of col-->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-sx-12">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item3 active">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div class="item3">
                        4
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic3" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic3" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </div><!--end of item-->
        </div><!--end of col-->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```